# How to access a public readonly Google spreadsheet from an Atom plugin?

Tags: google-sheets, atom-editor

I'm developing an Atom package that needs to read all data from a public readonly spreadsheet in Google Sheets, but I'm unsure about what to do.

I know I can use OAuth or an API key, but there are problems with each of these options. For OAuth, I need to setup an URI handler, and even though Atom has an URI handler (`atom://package-name`), it's not easily available in Linux, and Google only allows `https://` handlers. Now, about the API key, it can be used for testing, but it can't be published within the source code, which is necessary no publish the package.

So what to do? Just emphasizing that the *only* thing that needs to be accessed is a public readonly spreadsheet, so I guess no special access rights are required.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, how about using the web publish? The permission is read only. When Spreadsheet is published to Web, the URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml` is retrieved. By modifying this like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pub?gid=0&output=csv`, you can directly retrieve the data without using the API key and access token as the CSV data. But if you cannot publish the Spreadsheet to web, this method cannot be used. At that time, I have to apologize for my unuseful proposal.

Comment: Is your sheet public? Would you mind downloading it as a csv and then reading from it ? Then, this [other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55720172/12835757) might help. Otherwise, if you just want to retrieve the data and **the sheet is public** then [this tutorial](https://www.labnol.org/code/20004-google-spreadsheets-json) might help you. Please, let me know if your sheet is public as that makes things way easier, otherwise I believe there are workarounds.

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question, the sheet is public (public and readonly). I'll try what you both suggested and comment here.

Comment: So, the tutorial did work, it's basically a more detailed version of the first comment. Post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: That sounds great, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Public sheets do not require the use of the Google Sheets API to extract their json infromation from them nor they require the use of [oAuth 2](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing). You can simply achieve this by using a json `GET` request to them.

To get the json data from a public sheet you can use `jQuery`:

```js
$.getJSON(SHEET URL, function(data) {
  //data is the JSON string
});
```

[Here is a tutorial](https://www.labnol.org/code/20004-google-spreadsheets-json) with more information about how to achive this.

If you do not want to get the json with jQuery you can also use plain JavaScript as shown in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2499647/12835757).

> NOTE : This will only work if your sheet is public. To achieve this go to the sharing permissions and make it `Public`. You also will need to publish the sheet so that you can access the json data. Go to **File -> Publish to the web -> Publish**.

Comment: This approach no longer works and shows message "The Sheets v3 API has been turned down. Further information can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api"

Answer (score 0):

If you've enabled "Anyone with the link" sharing and the currently active sheet is the one you want to export, the url in the address bar can be transformed from this:

- `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/UNIQUE_KEY_HERE/edit#gid=UNIQUE_SHEET_ID`

To this:

- `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/UNIQUE_KEY_HERE/export?id=UNIQUE_KEY_HERE&gid=UNIQUE_SHEET_ID&format=tsv`

Single-sheet formats (requires `gid` parameter): `tsv`, `csv` and `ods`

Multi-sheet formats (`gid` is ignored): `xlsx` and `zip` (html)

PDF seems to use a different endpoint with `POST` instead of a `GET` so is the only Download format that can't be used with this URL.