# Reading CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to read the following `csv` so I can process it further but I am getting an `pandas.errors.ParserError`. I would really appreciate any help on how I can read it. Can you help me identify what I am doing wrong?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
logic_df = pd.read_csv("http://www.sharecsv.com/s/6c1b912f54d87d45f4728f8fb1510a5eb/random.csv")
```

I am not sure if there is something wrong with my `csv` because I used `csv` lint and it said my `csv` is fine so I am not sure what the issue is.

I also tried to do the following

```
logic_df = pd.read_csv("http://www.sharecsv.com/s/6cb912f54d87d45f4728f81fb1510a5eb/random.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the url to the direct link of the table should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv("http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/6cb912f54d87d45f4728f8fb1510a5eb/random.csv")
```

The thing is, your url is pointing to a html page, not a csv file per se. You can either use the url above, or reading the your url source with `pd.read_html`, like this:

```
df = pd.read_html('http://www.sharecsv.com/s/6cb912f54d87d45f4728f8fb1510a5eb/random.csv', header=0)[0]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's amazing what two letters can do.

Comment: I have no access to such file (it's not public). Furthermore, if you want to read a google sheet file, it's another issue. Please take a look at: [Google Sheets API for Python](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) or any other tutorial about it. If you decides to make your url public, then go to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55720172/7076819) from SO. It shows how to get the data from a public google sheet as csv.